# fill word with blanks

Tags: c, char

I have the following code but sometimes I get strange chars instead of blanks:

```
char *getWord(const char *string)
{
    char *chars = "-_";
    int len = 0;
    int max = 10;
    char *res = malloc(max + 1);
    for ( ; len<max; string++) {
        if(*string)
        {
            if (!strchr(chars, *string)) {
                res[len] = *string;
                ++ len;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            res[len] = ' ';
            ++ len;
        }
    }
    res[len] = 0;
    return res;
}
```

ex: char *mystring = "my-str_a"; //the result I want to be: "mystra" followed by 4 blanks: "mystra    "

How can I fill with blanks the end of the word until it reaches max length ?

Comment: Can you show examples of successes and failures?

Comment: When you increment `string` after you found the 0-terminator, you possibly/probably enter undefined-behaviour-territory.

Comment: I need the result to be exact 10 chars len and sometimes it is 5 or 8 or 12 or more. It cuts correctly if the length is >10 but doesn't fill with blanks if the len is 4. I guess it fills right if the string is >= 10 but when it is less than 10 it fills with strange chars

Comment: Yes, once you pass the end of `string`, you should quit looking at `*string`.

Comment: The extend @DanielFischer's answer, you always set max to the length of 10 but instead you should do `int max = strlen(string);`

Comment: and how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Original answer

One problem is that you are missing the `else` clause for `if (*string)`, which would need to set the character to blank.  Another problem is that you read past the end of the string.

```
char *getWord(const char *string)
{
    char *chars = "-_";
    int max = 10;
    int len;
    char *res = malloc(max + 1);
    if (res == 0)
        return res;
    for (len = 0; len < max; len++)
    {
        if (*string)
        {
            if (!strchr(chars, *string))
                res[len] = *string;
            else
                res[len] = ' ';
            string++;
        }
        else
            res[len] = ' ';
    }
    res[len] = 0;
    return res;
}
```

This uses a conventional `for (int len = 0; len < max; len++)` loop to step through the allocated array. The code only increments `string` when it is not pointing at the terminal null byte.  There is an assignment to `res[len]` on each iteration.  The code also checks that the memory allocation succeeds — important in real programs.

#### Revised answer

The function `getWord2()` does what you require.  Note the test harness.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static
char *getWord1(const char *string)
{
    char *chars = "-_";
    int max = 10;
    int len;
    char *res = malloc(max + 1);
    if (res == 0)
        return res;
    for (len = 0; len < max; len++)
    {
        if (*string)
        {
            if (!strchr(chars, *string))
                res[len] = *string;
            else
                res[len] = ' ';
            string++;
        }
        else
            res[len] = ' ';
    }
    res[len] = 0;
    return res;
}

static
char *getWord2(const char *string)
{
    char *chars = "-_";
    int max = 10;
    int len = 0;
    char *res = malloc(max + 1);
    if (res == 0)
        return res;
    while (len < max)
    {
        if (*string)
        {
            if (!strchr(chars, *string))
                res[len++] = *string;
            string++;
        }
        else
            res[len++] = ' ';
    }
    res[len] = 0;
    return res;
}


int main(void)
{
    const char *data[] =
    {
        "my-str_a",
        "--m--__",
        "my str a",
        "AbyssinianElephant",
        "--m--__m--m--m-m-m-m-m-m-m-m-m-m",
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]); i++)
    {
        char *res1 = getWord1(data[i]);
        char *res2 = getWord2(data[i]);
        char source[30];
        snprintf(source, sizeof(source), "<<%.25s>>", data[i]);
        assert(res1 != 0 && res2 != 0); // Reprehensible!

        printf("%-30.30s --> <<%s>> or <<%s>>\n", source, res1, res2);
        free(res1);
        free(res2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
<<my-str_a>>                   --> <<my str a  >> or <<mystra    >>
<<--m--__>>                    --> <<  m       >> or <<m         >>
<<my str a>>                   --> <<my str a  >> or <<my str a  >>
<<AbyssinianElephant>>         --> <<Abyssinian>> or <<Abyssinian>>
<<--m--__m--m--m-m-m-m-m-m->>  --> <<  m    m  >> or <<mmmmmmmmmm>>
```

If the 'mmmmmmmmmm' output isn't what you want, the specification needs tightening up a bit.  The tweaks probably aren't hard, but do need to be specified.

Comment: Jonathan, there is only one problem. It replaces -_ with blanks and I wanted to remove them.

Comment: the result from my-str_a is "my str a" instead of "mystra"

Comment: Updated answer — the `getWord2()` function behaves as I believe you want it to behave.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *getWord(const char *string)
{
    char *chars = "-_";
    size_t len ,max ;
    char *res ;

    max = 10;
    res = malloc(max + 1);
    if (!res) return 0;

    for (len = 0 ; *string && len < max; string++) {
        if (!strchr(chars, *string)) { res[len++] = *string; }
        }

    if (len < max) memset(res+len, ' ', max-len);
    res[max] = 0;
    return res;
}
```

Second version using strspn() / strcspn() (this might be faster if chars is larger than one or two characters)

```
char *getWord3(const char *string)
{
    char *chars = "-_";
    size_t dst,src,len ,max ;
    char *res ;

    max = 10;
    res = malloc(max + 1);
    if (!res) return 0;
    for (src=dst = 0 ; string[src] && dst < max; ) {
        len = strcspn( string+src, chars);
        if (len) {
                memcpy(res+dst,  string+src, len);
                src += len, dst += len;
                }
        len = strspn( string+src, chars);
        if (len) {
                src += len;
                }
        }

    if (dst < max) memset(res+dst, ' ', max-dst);
    res[max] = 0;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and for your time, but at the time you posted it I already accepted another answer so sorry for not accepting yours although I'm sure it's very good

Answer (score 0):

Much, much easier approach: just crawl along the string with a "read" and "write" pointer:

```
char *getWord(const char *string) {
    char *res = strdup(string);
    char *rp = res;
    char *wp = res;
    while(*rp) {
        if(*rp != '-' && *rp != '_') {
            *wp++ = *rp;
        }
        rp++;
    }
    while(wp < rp) {
        *wp++ = ' ';
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: but it doesn't limit to 10

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once you pass the terminating null of the variable `string`, you can't rely on `*string` to stay null. The result is that when `string` is less than `max` chars in length, you pick up whatever is in the bytes after the terminating null.

So, once you reach `strlen(string)`, you need to just pad with blanks until you reach `max`. I wouldn't advance the 'string' argument, but subscript it with 'len'.

```
stringlen = strlen(string);
for (; len < max; len++ )
  if (len >= stringlen) {
    res[len] = ' ';
  } else if (*string[len]) {
```

and so on.

Comment: I get a compilation error:  error: invalid type argument of `unary *'

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the first appearance of '\0' which marks the end of string. In your code for loop continues to iterate and copies all garbage characters after the end of the string (i.e. after '\0'). The garbage characters come from the fact that malloc reserves memory but does not clear it (does not setup values in memory to zero).